pgsql typeorm query is not working as expected in nestjs nodejs
I have this query to get the records based on some conditions
async getChangePayments(filter: DataFilterDto): Promise<ApiResponseDto> {
    const take = filter.count || 10;
    const pageNo = filter.pageNo > 0 ? filter.pageNo - 1 : 0;
    const skip = pageNo * take;

    // Start building the query
    const queryBuilder = this.paymentRepo.createQueryBuilder("payment");

    // Add conditions
    if (HelperService.isValueValid(filter.id)) {
      queryBuilder.andWhere("payment.id = :id", { id: filter.id });
    }

    if (HelperService.isValueValid(filter.enquiryId)) {
      queryBuilder.andWhere("payment.enquiryId = :enquiryId", { enquiryId: filter.enquiryId });
    }

    // Add filter conditions using the query builder
    queryBuilder
      .andWhere("payment.action IS NULL")
      .andWhere("payment.agreementId IS NOT NULL")
      .andWhere(`
  (agreementInfo.actual_payment_frequency = 7 AND 
          FLOOR(payment.paid_amount) != FLOOR(payment.actual_amount / 2))
          OR
          (agreementInfo.actual_payment_frequency != 7 AND 
          payment.paid_amount != payment.actual_amount)
  `);

    // Add relations
    queryBuilder.leftJoinAndSelect("payment.createdByUser", "createdByUser")
      .leftJoinAndSelect("payment.agreementInfo", "agreementInfo")
      .leftJoin("agreementInfo.applicantInfo", "agreementInfo.applicantInfo")
      .addSelect([
        "agreementInfo.applicantInfo.id",
        "agreementInfo.applicantInfo.name"
      ]);

    // Set order, take, and skip
    queryBuilder.orderBy("payment.paidDate", "ASC")
      .take(take)
      .skip(skip);

    // Execute the query
    const [result, total] = await queryBuilder.getManyAndCount();

    return { data: result, count: total };
  }

but this query is returnig the records where action is not null.
I have tried a lot, but not getting what is the issue
Update 1
i changed the where clause to
.andWhere(`FLOOR(payment.paid_amount) != FLOOR(payment.actual_amount / (14 / agreementInfo.actual_payment_frequency))`);

and printed this query (added where clause fields to test and removed extra fields)
SELECT "payment"."id" AS "payment_id",
        "payment"."actual_amount" AS "actual_amount", 
    "payment"."paid_amount" AS "paid_amount", "payment"."paid_date" AS "paid_date",
    "payment"."action" AS "payment_action", 
    "createdByUser"."id" AS "User_id",
    FLOOR("payment"."paid_amount") as value1,
    FLOOR("payment"."actual_amount" / (14 / "agreementInfo"."actual_payment_frequency")) as value2,
    "agreementInfo"."id" AS "agreementInfo_id",  "agreementInfo.applicantInfo"."id" AS "applicantInfo_id"
    FROM "payments" "payment" 
    LEFT JOIN "users" "createdByUser" ON "createdByUser"."id"="payment"."created_by"
    LEFT JOIN "agreements" "agreementInfo" ON "agreementInfo"."id"="payment"."agreement_id"  
    LEFT JOIN "applicants" "agreementInfo.applicantInfo" ON "agreementInfo"."applicant_id"="agreementInfo"."applicant_id" 
    WHERE "payment"."action" IS NULL 
        AND "payment"."agreement_id" IS NOT NULL 
        AND FLOOR("payment"."paid_amount") != FLOOR("payment"."actual_amount" / (14 / "agreementInfo"."actual_payment_frequency")) 
    ORDER BY "payment"."paid_date" ASc
    limit 5;

and this is showing

duplicate payment ids but from hitting api no duplicate records.

A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Also show us your current SQL attempt.

this is bit strange, if i get the sql query from the above query builder , and execute it gives the different result set than this orm query running on nodejs
